# Не работает ng-include AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Установил xampp. Разрабатываю проект на AngularJS. Есть часть страницы, которую я хочу вынести в отдельный файл (Меню навигации). Использую для реализации директиву ng-include. Первый раз всё подтягивается нормально, а потом, если я, например, убрал из: Главная О проекту Контакты" контакты, то после перезагрузки страницы остаётся та версия, которую я загрузил изначально. После перезагрузки сервера всё равно ничего не обновляется. Хотя надписи Контакты уже и в помине нет. Почему так?

```
<!doctype html>
<html  ng-app="mainPageApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
<ng-include src="'headMenu.html'"></ng-include>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновляй страницу используя <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (в зависимости от браузера).

Ну или используй другой сервер, который не будет выставлять кэширующие заголовки.

Comment: Работает, спасибо!